# What is the most effecient way to reduce (combine) an array containing objects?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I have an array of objects containing a `partId` and a `quantity`. I want for each `partId` in the final array to be unique, by summing the `quantity` of objects with the same `partId`.

I want this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [partId] => 232032
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [partId] => 232032
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [partId] => 232031
            [quantity] => 1
        )
)
```

To end up like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [partId] => 232032
            [quantity] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [partId] => 232031
            [quantity] => 1
        )
)
```

---

Here's what I'm doing now, I feel like there has to be a better way.

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item->partId, $tmp)) {
        $tmp[$item->partId]->quantity += $item->quantity;
    } else {
        $tmp[$item->partId] = $item;
    }
}
$array2 = array_merge($tmp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item->partId, $tmp)) {
        $array1[$tmp[$item->partId]]->quantity += $item->quantity;
        unset($array1[$key]);
    } else {
        $tmp[$item->partId] = $key;
    }
}

print_r($array1);
```

Comment: So this is saving the `partId,key` pair in the temporary table rather than the objects themselves, and manipulating the original array... is that right?

Comment: @nachito Yes. You only have a temporary array that can be unset after the foreach. The original array is manipulated - either the quantity is added and the duplicate is unset or a new record to the temporary array is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `isset()` is slightly faster than `array_key_exists`,
so you could do

```
if ( isset($tmp[$item->partId]) || array_key_exists($item->partId, $tmp) )
{
    ...
}
```

That would give you a slight boost.

I do like your algorithm though.

Comment: When using `isset($tmp[$item->partId])` there is no need to call `|| array_key_exists($item->partId, $tmp)` - preferably I would use `isset`, didn't come to my mind :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably using an associative array as a temporary data structure with the partId as the key, then iterate through the original and for each element either insert the object into the temporary associative array if the key's value is null otherwise increment the existing object by the quantity from the object in the original array.

Comment: I almost posted this same answer but after looking at his algorithm, that's exactly what he is doing! :)

Comment: But to increment the quantity only is not enough - he has to add duplicate entry's quantity to the original one's...

Comment: Yes, you'd increment by the value in the original array, increment needn't mean 'increase by one'.

Comment: @Baxter OK, I'm sorry, I thought You meant it like increase by one. Again, sorry!

Comment: He is doing += $item->quantity after already setting the element's quantity to the first occurrence's quantity.  He's already doing your suggestion.